# Touches command is not working due to scroll view

Tags: swift

Hi I am new to swift programming. I wanted to created an app that can allow user to draw on an image and the drawing feature works however when I added scrollview it seems to be blocking the touch command that is suppose to be meant for the imageView is there any thing I can do to allow the user to draw on the image and keep the scrollView? the scrollView is there so that the user can zoom in and out of the image

```
let strokeColor:UIColor = UIColor.red

let lineWidth:CGFloat = 1.0

var path = UIBezierPath()
var shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
var croppedImage = UIImage()

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imageView.image = img
    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return self.imageView
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first as UITouch?{
        let touchPoint = touch.location(in: self.imageView)
        path.move(to: touchPoint)
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first as UITouch?{
        let touchPoint = touch.location(in: self.imageView)
        path.addLine(to: touchPoint)
        addNewPathToImage()
    }
}

override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first as UITouch?{
        let touchPoint = touch.location(in: self.imageView)
        path.close()
    }
}

func addNewPathToImage(){
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = strokeColor.cgColor
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
    imageView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}
```

Comment: When you let them use the touch, set the isUserInteractionEnabled property of the scroll view to false.

Comment: @ElTomato Thank you for your reply. I have tried this method works however it also disable the function which allows the user to zoom in and out of the image.

Comment: Install a switch control on the screen and let them decide when to set the isUserInteractionEnabled property true or false.

Comment: @ElTomato I will try it. once again thank you very much for your help